# How to add associated text for input text in Struts html?

Tags: java, html, struts, rpt

```
<tr>
<td valign="top" width="150">
<label for="MFYR">Maximum Factory Year</label>
<!-- <label for="MFYR"><span style="color: rgb(255, 51, 0);" class="fnt">*</span></label></td> SKL-->
<span id="MFYR" style="color: rgb(255, 51, 0);" class="fnt">*</span>

<td width="7"><br />
</td>
<td valign="top" width="140">
<%-- <html:text styleId="MFYR" property="maximumFactotyYear" size="15"  styleClass="iform" /></td> --%>
<html:text id="MFYR" property="maximumFactotyYear" size="15" styleClass="iform"
```

/>

This is the code that is there. Now using Rational Policy Tester(RPT), I am getting an policy violation of "Each form control must have associated text."... Please an someone help me in sorting out this issue. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the id of `<span id="MFYR">`, because it conflicts with id of your `<html:text>`. That's probably why `<label>` is confused.